# Facebook PHP SDK - Cannot make requests for user info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having some trouble making requests through the Facebook API. I've already got the access token, but when i make a request, i get the exception:

> Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'You must provide an access token

I'm 100% sure that i've provided the access token because i can store it to a $_SESSION variable. Here's the code:

```
if (isset($accessToken)) {
  echo "LOGGED IN!";
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  #Here is where it crashes -> I know it should be sorrounded by try/catch, but it crashes even so.
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
}
```

I'm following their step-by-step configuration but got stuck here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How would Facebook know the access token just because you store it in a session variable?

Comment: Fixed:  

It was missing $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken)

thx